# Submit form as array and remove special characters

Tags: php, arrays, forms, htmlspecialchars

How would one perform htmlspecialchars on a form that is submitted as an array like this:

```
<input name="sv_votes[][author]" />
<input name="sv_votes[][author]" />
<input name="sv_votes[][author]" />
```

This does not seem to do anything:

```
htmlspecialchars($_POST['sv_votes'])
```

Comment: Is that going to be an `Array` of `Arrays`? or just an `Array`? Your example could be better because they all have the same name. I can't understand what kind of data structure you have.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through array.

```
foreach($_POST['sv_votes'] as $key => $value){
    $_POST['sv_votes'][$key] = htmlspecialchars($value);
}
```